# How to redirect to and call a script from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to redirect to a url in javascript and specify, at the beginning of this other page, that another script should be executed after the page has finished loading?

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
<a href="/to/other/page">
```

Then, on the other page, it would execute this function:

```
function myFunction () {
    //do something
}
```

However, this function wouldn't be called when visiting `/to/other/page` normally, but only when redirected from the given link.

I tried a lot of things, but everything said that script behind the redirect isn't done anymore. I can't find a way to send the new script to the redirected page.

Comment: Do you want to load the script no matter what or under certain circumstances? For example, only load the scripts on `B` if coming from `A` or just whenever visiting `B`?

Comment: Can you show some of the "lots of things" you've tried?  It would be easier to help you :)

Comment: Do you have control over the 'second' page (i.e. the page the user is redirected TO)? As in, can you add code there?

Comment: Certainly not, that would be a great vulnerability. Unless, as mentioned, it is a page that you have control of (i.e. your website) you could send a GET-value or similar and act accordingly.

Comment: I don't have control about the pages. The main-script i need works fine if i use the console of chrome or firefox on the 'second' page, but i need to get there by a redirect from the first page...

"lots of things" means i know some different solutions to redirect to a page, like:document.location.href=url, $.get(url)

Comment: It's not possible to execute scripts from outside the page. You can't redirect someone to another url, and then execute a script from the previous page you were on. That would cause **massive** security issues, since it would be easy to just execute a little script that would send your server all of the user's facebook data by redirecting them to facebook and then executing a data-crawling script there.

Comment: What do you even need this for? Perhaps you can try making an extension which people can install, but executing a script on another page, from your own page, is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

To load a script no matter what:

```
<body onload="myfunction()"> ...

<script>
    function myfunction() {
    //do whatever here
    }
</script>
```

If you only want to load the function when coming from, say, `http://example.com/A`, implement the following script:

```
<script>
    var hash = window.location.hash || "";
    if (hash === "#A"){
        //do the following
    }
</script>
```

Now, all you have to do is make sure that, for page `http://example.com/A`, you make links to page `B` like this: `http://example.com/B#A`. This is  really rudimentary way of detecting page loads from other pages, but it'll probably serve your needs.

**edit:** Alternatively, since you tagged `jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //do whatever here
})
```

This causes the script to run whenever the document has finished loading. Note, there is a difference [`$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and [`$(window).load(function(){ ... })`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Answer (score 0):

Please view one of these

[Javscript Redirect Tutorial 1](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php)

//german
[Javascript Redirect Tutorial 2](http://www.websmith.de/blog/webprogrammierung/redirect-suchmaschinen/redirect-mit-javascript-21/)

you may also take a look at following keywords .htaccess; SEO friendly URL;
with this you can redirect the user and on the other page you can load what you wish to

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at all. You cannot possibly run a script on another page. You can't redirect someone to another url, and then execute a script on that page. That would cause **massive** security issues, since it would be easy to just execute a little script that would send your server all of the user's facebook data by redirecting them to facebook, and then executing a data-crawling script there.

So in short: no, this isn't possible, and you should be glad it isn't, otherwise I'd know all of your passwords by now.

PS: redirecting a page is possible to do quite easily using a meta refresh tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

which will redirect you to http://example.com/ when the page loads.